# Display package info of all available packages across all repos in OpenSuse

Tags: opensuse, zypper

I am a beginner to zypper and I am trying to display the package info of all available packages in OpenSuse across all repos.

```
zypper info #Or

zypper info * # doesn't seem to work
```

needs a package as an argument. Could any command be suggested that can make this happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will result in a very large output that your terminal settings might not support at all (you will have to configure them for showing `N` number of lines). Or if you redirect the output to a file you could get a  very large file

---

The `*` does not work because your shell (bash,zsh) interprets as a wildcard expansion.

If you are using `bash` try using this:

```bash
set -f
zypper info *
```

In `zsh` you use:

```bash
noglob zypper info *
```

---

Or you can simply quote the `*` between single quotes or double quotes (this works for any shell, AFAIK):

```bash
zypper info '*'
```

Comment: Thank you! That works!